# EF7 and SQLite big troubles, can I use SQL Server CE with Mobile?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-core

Well this is the final love story, I was developing an UWP app firstly for phones. I was using EF7 with SQLite and everything works pretty well.

But what a surprise migrations doesn't work at all, a simple task as add a column throws `System.NotSupportedException`. Of course there is a lot of solutions as create another table.. then move data... then rename.... then delete and so on...

Almost 8 steps just to add a column.

Well I think it is a huge amount of work with SQLite.

Now my question is : can I use SQL Server CE v4 with EF7 Core  in phones?

I was reading about it, but all GITHUB docs talks about traditional desktop applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Windows Phones use a different processor arcnitcture, that is not supported by Sql Server Compact. Maybe have a look at ESENT?

Comment: Don't know about ESENT, But I'm going to take a look to it. is ESENT compatible with EF?

Comment: Not at the moment, no

Comment: the related EF github issue is here in all its ugliness https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4423